# Use the Google account sign in authentication for apps in Android

Tags: android, authentication, gmail, google-account

I am creating an app which needs sign-in. On the desktop (full) website, he can sign-in with the existing Google account. On mobiles, how can I make the user sign-in with the Google account using on his android phone.
Will Android allow me to use his existing Google account to sign into my app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app

Answer (score 3):

You're probably not using the app engine, but I think there must be a way to [use this example](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app) up to a point.  I think that if you get to the point where you're calling:

```
accountManager.getAuthToken(account, "ah", false, new GetAuthTokenCallback(), null);
```

and then processing the callback, you should be able to determine if the user has logged in based on whether a login intent comes back or the user token comes back.  If you're not going to use the token you can just disregard it, knowing the user has authenticated their account.  Sorry if this isn't helpful.  That's my experience with the AccountManager as of yet.